# What's new in winter '15 for developers

Tags: developer, release, pre-release, winter15

Edited: What's new in winter '15 for developers?

I was looking for something specific for developers. I ran into some beta versions of duplicate rules, which I believe comes under data.com. I found this https://cs7.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter15_release_spotlight.pdf, a spotlight, which is a light version of the release notes, which is again in beta.

I also checked out that there are some changes to how static resources are being served, I really couldn't figure out what advantages it could have.

Now that I have some specifics, can you please help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: Akash, you might want to take a look at [help/how-to-ask]. The answer to the question you just asked could have easily been found with a quick Google search or by simply visiting [Developer.Force](https://www.developer.salesforce.com/), a site I'd hope any developer would want to become familiar with since it is the repository for all documents related to Salesforce.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't looking for a very generic documentation, that I'm sure I could have got it from a simple google search. I was looking anything specific, that's why I had "is there any big change?" in my question. The aim of my question is to share to my developer friends any new developments, thereby creating a healthy discussion on the same. Thanks for down-voting.

Comment: Again, take a look at [Help]. Your question is very broad and subjective. In my opinion, its beyond the scope of this forum, thus the downvote; something I rarely do. And when I do, I always comment to tell someone why I've downvoted their question. What's "big" to you, may be of minor consequence to others. If you had a specific question about an upcoming change, I'd have absolutely no issues with that. There are numerous blogs that discuss the highlights of what's coming, all of which can be found via a Google search. My favorite SF search engine is http://findsf.info/.

Comment: There are certain things not everyone runs into and there's a nice way of sharing it. like the  findsf.info site, which most of us don't know. Again, what looks like a small thing to you is a big thing for some others, and I believe this stackexchange is specifically for that-to bridge the gap. I don't wanna argue more and draw flak. Thanks for the info on the search site, though it's just a google powered search. But, I'll take your point and edit my question. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome for the search engine link. I find it to be a very helpful one to use that someone here pointed me to a long time ago. It cuts out a lot of the garbage a regular Google search returns. Now that you've rephrased your question, I've no issues with it and have reversed my downvote. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation page is: https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter%2015

Canvas updates:
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter15/Canvas15Enhancements

Salesforce 1:
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter15/S1MobileDev

Visualforce:
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter15/VFEnhancements

I also find this success community "Success - Release Readiness" useful, although not primarily developer focused. This should be the url: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oku

The duplicate alert has no dependency on having access to data.com - it's being developed by the data.com team hence they have used the name (confusingly so!). I know this is the case as my org is on the pilot.

Comment: The duplicate alert has no dependency on data.com - I've updated my answer to include that.